# MATLAB: fprintf of scandinavien letters æ, ø å

Tags: matlab, printf, special-characters

I am having trouble with printing the scandinavien letter Ø using fprintf in MatLab, it returns the HEX numeric character reference xD8 in my txt file. Anyone know a way around this issue?

Cheers
Sam

Comment: Any more information on version, OS, etc? ``[fid,err]=fopen('asd.txt','w');fprintf(fid,'ÆØÅ\n');fclose(fid);`` returns the expected outcome (ÆØÅ in the text-file) w/ R2016a on Win10.

Comment: Hi,
Running Win7 with R2015b.
This is quite strange, it seems to be working in a simple example as above.. I will try and dig into what goes wrong in my program. Thanks for the answer mate!